# Mysql "BEFORE UPDATE" trigger strange behaviour for table with two timestamp columns

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp, updates

I am using mysql - ( mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.67, for suse-linux-gnu (x86_64) )

I have a table "MyTable",  that has three columns - a column "Col1" of type  "varchar" and two columns  "UpdateTime" and "InsertTime" of type "timestamp"

I want to use InsertTime to track time of record insertion and UpdateTime to track time of record update.

mysql> describe MyTable;

```
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | 

+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+

|Col1                   | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL                |

|InsertTime             | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 


|UpdateTime             | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I have a trigger definition as follows that is expected to ensure that when MyTable is updated the InsertTime   timestamp will be preserved to original creation one , but the UpdateTime timestamp will be updated to current time stamp

```
 DELIMITER $$
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `MyTable_UPDATE`;  $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `MyTable_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    SET NEW.`UpdateTime` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
    SET NEW.`InsertTime` = OLD.`InsertTime`;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is when I update "MyTable" as follows

```
update MyTable set Col1=NULL ;
```

Then the InsertTime value is also getting set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP along with UpdateTime .
This problem goes away ( It preserves InsertTime ) if I change the trigger definition to as follows ( by getting rid of assignment to UpdateTime - which is not what I want)

```
DELIMITER $$
 DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `MyTable_UPDATE`;  $$
 CREATE TRIGGER `MyTable_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    # SET NEW.`UpdateTime` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
    # -- THIS DOES NOT HELP ME I WANT UpdateTime to be updated 
    SET NEW.`InsertTime` = OLD.`InsertTime`;
 END $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Is this a BUG or is this expected behavior.
How can I get this to work ?

I tried to perform an alter table as follows

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable`
CHANGE COLUMN `UpdateTime` `UpdateTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

But that gives me an error as follows

"Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause"

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Yogesh

Comment: Change your UpdateTime field to datetime  hope it will slove your problem

Comment: I've tested your case in Postgres and it all seems to be working here. SQLFiddle is OOS right now, unfortunately.

Comment: Sure - This works fine on older mysql versions, but with this particular version I have problems ...

Comment: We tested it on Mysql 5.6.22 version DB and it behaved the same way ...